# Appcelerator Titanium Android Login and go to tab

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, titanium, appcelerator

Hi I need to create an application that uses Android system and then login as you have the correct credentials to go to a window with tabs.

I have this code for authentication in app.js, it works fine for now but I have not managed to create the structure of tabs.

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor: '#096594', 
    title: 'ACCESS CONFIG', 
    layout:'vertical',
    navBarHidden:true,
    fullscreen:false, 
     exitOnClose:true
});

var my_navbar = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    height:20,
    backgroundColor:'#989898',
    color:'#fff',
    text:'  ACCESS CONFIG',
    top:0,
    width:'100%',
    font:{fontSize:11,fontWeight:'normal'},
    marginleft:10
});
win.add(my_navbar);

win.add(Ti.UI.createLabel({
    top:10, 
    height:15, 
    left:10, 
    right:5,
    color:'#fff',
    textAlign:'left',
    text:'Usuario: [Userid]', 
    font:{fontSize:12},
    bottom:5
}));

var txtUserid = Ti.UI.createTextField({
    value:'1',
    hintText:'user ID',
    height:35, 
    left:5, 
    right:5,
    font:{fontSize:12},
    color:'#a2a2a2',
    borderStyle:Ti.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED 
}); 
win.add(txtUserid);

win.add(Ti.UI.createLabel({
    top:2, 
    height:17, 
    left:10, 
    right:5,
    color:'#fff',
    textAlign:'left',
    text:'Name: [Login]', 
    font:{fontSize:12},
    bottom:5
}));

var txtLogin = Ti.UI.createTextField({
    value:'M',
    hintText:'Username',
    height:35, 
    left:5, 
    right:5,
    font:{fontSize:12},
    color:'#a2a2a2',
    borderStyle:Ti.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED 
}); 
win.add(txtLogin);  

win.add(Ti.UI.createLabel({
    top:2, 
    height:17, 
    left:10, 
    right:5,
    color:'#fff',
    textAlign:'left',
    text:'Password: [Password]', 
    font:{fontSize:12},
    bottom:5
}));

var txtPassword = Ti.UI.createTextField({
    value:'111',
    hintText:'Contraseña',
    passwordMask:true,
    height:35, 
    left:5, 
    right:5,
    font:{fontSize:12},
    color:'#a2a2a2',
    borderStyle:Ti.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED 
}); 
win.add(txtPassword);

win.add(Ti.UI.createLabel({
    top:10,
    height:0, 
    left:5, 
    right:5,
    color:'#000',
    textAlign:'left',
    text:'Authentication Url:', 
    font:{fontSize:18}
    }));

var txtUrl = Ti.UI.createTextField({
    value:'http://',
    hintText:'Url to connect with data',
    height:0, left:5, right:5,
    borderStyle:Ti.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED 
}); 
win.add(txtUrl);


var yesButton = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title:'Connect with DATA', 
    top:5, 
    height:37, 
    left:85, 
    right:85,
    color:'#fff',
    backgroundColor:'#406a83',
    borderColor:'#688a9d',
    borderWidth:1,
    borderRadius:5,
    borderStyle:Ti.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_BEZEL   
});
win.add(yesButton);


yesButton.addEventListener('click', clickYesButton);

function clickYesButton(e) {
    var button = e.source;
    var xhr=Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();   
    xhr.onerror = function(e){alert('Error: '+e.error);};
    xhr.onload = function() {alert(this.responseText);};
    xhr.open("POST",txtUrl.value);//ADD your URL
    var param={"userid":txtUserid.value,"login":txtLogin.value,"password":txtPassword.value};
    Ti.API.info('Params'+JSON.stringify(param));
    xhr.send(param);
}

win.open();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a default tabbed-application from the new project options.  This will show you how a tabbed application is built.  You could rename the JS files and copy them to your current project.  Insert the window open call from the tabbed-window application into your successful authentication function and open it.  The window should open over the top of your previous window with the authentication code.